# Representation of $SO^{+}(3,1)$ for scalar fields

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, inertial-frames, group-theory, representation-theory

As far as i know, the generators of the representation of the group of the orthochronous Lorentz transformations $SO^{+}(3,1)$ can bewritten in the following form:
$$J^{\mu \nu} = i(x^{\mu}\partial^{\nu}-x^{\nu}\partial^{\mu})$$
So this would mean that we could write for the Lorentz transformation of the scalar field $\phi(x)$:
$$\phi'(x')=\exp(i\omega_{\mu \nu}J^{\mu \nu})\phi(x)$$
But i know that the scalar field is invariant under Lorentz transformations, so
$$\phi'(x')=\phi(x)$$
How can these two expressions not contradict each other? If one expands the exponent, i.e.
$$\exp(i\omega_{\mu \nu}J^{\mu \nu})=1+i\omega_{\mu \nu}J^{\mu \nu}+O(\omega^2)$$ then one has terms like $i\omega_{12}i(x\partial_y-y\partial_x)+\ ...$

Why does this exponential acting on the scalar field leave the scalar field invariant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scalar field transforms in the trivial representation of the Lorentz group, so $J^{\mu\nu} = 0$ for scalar fields.

The equation $J^{\mu\nu} = \mathrm{i}\left(x^\mu\partial^\nu - x^\nu \partial^\mu\right)$ is only true when momentum is represented as $p^\mu = \partial^\mu$, i.e. this expression is for $J^{\mu\nu}$ acting on a *wavefunction*, not on a quantum field.

Note that there are two different representations you can think of in the context of a quantum field - the finite-dimensional one on the classical target space of the field, and the infinite-dimensional unitary one on the space of states of the quantum theory, see also [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/215548/50583). The statement $J^{\mu\nu} = 0$ for a scalar field is in the context of the *finite-dimensional* representation.

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at here. Lorentz transformations don't leave a (quantum or classical) scalar field invariant. If a scalar field were invariant under all spatial rotations about all origins, then it would be spatially uniform (translation-invariant), but scalar fields certainly aren't translation-invariant: $\phi(x')\neq \phi(x)$.

Comment: $J^{\mu\nu}$ is indeed $0$ for a scalar field. This is how one will get the third equation from the second. It is true that $\phi(x')\neq \phi(x)$ but $\phi'(x')=\phi(x)$. @ChiralAnomaly

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Ah, yes, of course there is a third representation here - the representation of Lorentz transformations on the space of (scalar) functions. I'm just saying that the representation *on the target space of the scalar field* is trivial, not that the representation *on the space of scalar functions* is trivial, which is what you're pointing out.